# Sequencing Release pipelines based on dependencies

Tags: sql-server, msbuild, azure-devops, sqlpackage

We have implemented **DevOps** for our, ***SQLServer based,*** database releases on **Azure DevOps** using **MSBuild** (to create the dacpac in the build pipeline) 
and **sqlpackage.exe** (for deploying the dacpacs).

The build pipeline results in two **dacpacs** (one for ***DatabaseOne*** and the other for ***DatabaseTwo***) and we use sqlpackage to release the dacpacs.

We are facing a scenario where in a single change set

***a. In DatabaseOne there is a change to a stored procedure, which references a new table in DatabaseTwo***

***b. We are creating the new table in DatabaseTwo***

*There is an error when deploying the changes because sequentially*, DatabaseOne is deployed before DatabaseTwo. The deployment succeeds upon retry but we 
are looking for a solution that works in general.

Has anyone come across such an need?

Comment: Can you deploy database2 before database1?

Comment: Manually yes. Only if I know that there is such a dependency in advance from the developers. But the deployment pipeline (Build & Release) is automated. With in a dacpac package, SQLPackage handles such dependencies gracefully but not when dependencies span dacpacs.